# How to extend Tiled and Cocos2d to create an Isometric map that supports elevation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, isometric, tilemap

I've been looking and looking and looking, and I cannot seem to find a solution out there for making a game that uses cocos2d and [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) to make an isometric map that supports elevation.

I am not looking for anything super complex...

Just maybe 2 or 3 levels of elevation. (Think X-Com UFO Defense, or Final Fantasy Tactics)

I figure that since I've been unable to find a solution, I'll probably have to extend Tiled or something to support this.

For now I'll just stick with level of elevation, but I want to extend the game to support elevation eventually.

**Will you share with me any good resources that you know? Where should I read to better understand how to accomplish such a thing?**

Comment: Do you need something like a building that has several floors (as seen as in X-Com games), or just different ground-levels, maybe with ramps?

Comment: Great question bummzack... I could go for either really, but I think just different ground-levels would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just opened Tiled and saw that there's support for multiple layers. So you could even build multiple ground-levels inside Tiled.

For different height-levels, you probably won't need the multiple layers at all. You could build that just by using special tiles, something like shown [here](http://opengameart.org/content/isometric-64x64-outside-tileset) or [here](http://opengameart.org/content/isoball-project-tiles). The type of tile would also denote the height. If you have special areas like a ramp that maybe spans across several tiles, you can use the "objects" in Tiled to add such metadata to your map.

It's basically the same approach as you would add walls in an isometric game.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the links. I will look into this over the next few weeks and come back with more comments or questions.